# Relative/Absolute precision of Newton's method

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I was asked to calculate the relative and absolute precision of my implementation of Newton's method and I wanted to make sure I understand it correctly.

According to the method:

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

So if I understand correctly:

1. Absolute error is $\frac{|f(x_n)|}{|f'(x_n)|}$
2. Relative error is $\frac{|x_{n+1}|}{|x_n|}$

Is that correct?

Comment: Which is the same as mine, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If:

- $x_{\infty}$ is precise value you want to find
- $x_{n+1}$ your best approximation

then [absolute error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error) $\epsilon$ will be :

$$\epsilon =  | x_{\infty} - x_{n+1}|$$

and relative error $\eta$ will be:

$$  \eta = \frac{\epsilon}{|x_{\infty}|}$$